# Can I decompile a *.chm file to html with a html TOC using MS HTML Workshop? If not how can I?

Tags: html, chm, tableofcontents

When I decompile I get an hhc file and a hhk file and no index.html. Can I get MS HTML Workshop to generate a html table of contents index.html file instead when decompiling? If not is there any other free software I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik no. Creating a basic toc->html export would be very easy, since it is essentially a XML to html transformation, but it probably won't be in the style of the rest of the CHM.

Maybe one of the Unix CHM viewers perform such step to view the TOC with a html viewer somewhere. But recycling such code would probably be more work than rewriting it.